# I quit a master’s program for a PhD program. How do I list this on my CV?

Tags: phd, masters, job-search, cv

Before starting my PhD, I was enrolled in a master’s program for one year that I quit once I got accepted to my current PhD program.

What do you think I should write on my CV so as not to give a bad impression to potential employers?

- > University A, 2016 to present
  > B.Sc., University B, 2015
- > University A, 2016 to present
  > MA program, University B, 2015–2016 (quit to start PhD at A)
  > B.Sc., University B, 2015
- > University A, 2016 to present
  > B.Sc., University B, 2015 (followed by a one-year enrollment in the master’s program)
- something else?

Comment: Who are your potential employers? Academia or industry?

Comment: @user111388 Academia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest something like "left to pursue PhD" rather than "quit" or "abandoned". The explicit meaning is the same, but there is an implicit negativity in quitting or abandoning something.

> PhD student, Dept of Rocket Science, University A, 2016 to present (expected Spring 2032)
>
> MA student, University B, 2015-2016 (left to pursue PhD)
>
> B.Sc. Physics, University B, 2015

(I'd also probably add the program name/degree titles and anticipated graduation date)

In your case, it's a short enough window that you could also probably leave it off without any notice, especially if you are applying to industry positions.

One time to definitely not leave it off is *anything asking for your full academic record* - the cases where this typically applies are in graduate admissions (which likely longer apply to you) and some grant applications (which still could).

Answer (score -1):

Your second version seems clearest, but the wording might be "Abandoned on acceptance to doctoral program". And state on the first line that you are in a doctoral program. Give complete years for BSc.

> Doctoral Program, University A, 2016 to present
> MA Program, University B, 2015–2016 (abandoned on acceptance to doctoral program)
> B.Sc., University B, 2013–2015 (or whatever)

Opinion, though. Just make it as clear as possible. One line for each program.

Comment: I would probably stick with something like "left to pursue PhD" rather than "quit" or "abandoned". The explicit meaning is the same, but there is an implicit negativity in quitting or abandoning something.

Comment: @BryanKrause  What about the first option where I just don't write anything about programs that I didn't finish? It looks bad because I look like I did nothing between 2015 and 2016?